# torch.squeeze and torch.unsqueeze equivalent in Flashlight (arrayfire)

Tags: c++, flashlight, arrayfire

I'm porting PyTorch code to Flashlight code. What is an Arrayfire or Flashlight function equivalent for `squeeze` and `unsqueeze` in Pytorch?

`processed_query = self.query_layer(query.unsqueeze(1))`

`energies = energies.squeeze(-1)`

How to convert this to Arrayfire code? (or, flashlight?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [af::moddims](http://arrayfire.org/docs/group__manip__func__moddims.htm) function:

```cpp
array a = randu(10, 1, 10, 10);
squeezed_a = moddims(a, 10, 10, 10);
```